# Modern UI desktop design using .NET

Tags: c#, user-interface, desktop

wondering how to create such app like Microsoft Expression Blend 4, with the modern design.

[image]

Very interested with the scroll and tab panel. The scroll is modern look, small and thin, unlike those wide scroll bars normally found in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 6):

Expression Blend 4 is a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Application.

WPF allows you to customize nearly every aspect of the UI (including the scrollbars if you'd like).

Since you specifically call out the scroll panels, here's a tutorial that shows you specifically how to customize the look of the scroll bar by modifying the WPF template:

[sachabarber.net >> Styling a ScrollViewer/Scrollbar in WPF](http://sachabarber.net/?p=122)

The nice thing about WPF is that once you understand how to modify things by changing their template, you can use the same method to change the look/feel of just about anything.

Comment: I would say that instead of "you _can_ change" it is more of a "you _have to_ change". This is a disadvantage in my opinion, compared to e.g. Windows Forms.

Comment: @Uwe - You're never forced to change anything in WPF. You can use everything as it looks out of the box. The same can be said for WinForms. WinForms on the other hand is far less flexible in allowing you to style the elements for a Rich Interface.

Comment: hi Uwe Keim, why "you have to change". WPF and windows controls have the same appearance by default right? So only if we want nicer UI then we need to change, no?

Comment: Thanks, guys. I never did a real project with WPF, just some examples. The degrees of freedom are huge compared to Windows Forms.

Answer (score 3):

You could use DevExpress components for [Windows Forms](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/) or [WPF](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/).

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: I would also suggest DevExpress

Comment: I am also for DevExpress

Comment: I also tried (and even bought) Infragistics. Beside that the usage of the controls was rather "strange" to me, the look-and-feel also was way below the quality of the DevExpress components.

Comment: thanks guys for the quick response! before I always thought that WPF can do nice UI by default but apparently not :( Now have to decide whether to use winform or WPF. Looking at one of the comment below abt WPF themes, means for winform, it's a totaly new control, but for WPF it's only theme applied to the controls? Just like CSS applied to web page? Sorry, been doing web, but new to WPF.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is the way to go.  Look at some of the themes [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes) to get an idea.

There is even an Expression Dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a sweet WinForms suite that has many sleek looking controls. That might be a good starting point.

Comment: thanks, I've got 3 options now, DevExpress, Infragistics, and Telerik. But need to pay for those. The WPF theme is the right (and free) way to go, I think.